# UNIX - Simple merging of two files as in the input

Tags: shell, unix

Input File1:

```
HELLO
HOW
```

Input File2:

```
ARE
YOU
```

output file should be

```
HELLO
HOW
ARE
YOU
```

My input files will be in one folder and my script has to fetch the input files from that folder and merge all the files as in the above given order.

Thanks

Comment: please clarify your input files contains and output file contains
I can't getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `cat` as shown below:

```
cat file1 file2
```

or, to concatenate all files in a folder (assuming there are not too many):

```
cat folder/*
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! when i try above command i m getting op like HOWARE in same line

Comment: that means that you do not have a newline at the end of your file. You should make sure your files end with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '' file1 file2
```

hope this works fine +

Answer (score 0):

cat:

```
cat file1 file2 >output
```

perl:

```
perl -plne '' file1 file2 >output
```

awk:

```
awk '1' file1 file2 >output
```